# Store result of system call in R object

Tags: r

I have the following simple python code:

```
import sys
print(int(sys.argv[2])+int(sys.argv[1]))
```

stored in `myScript.py`

I call this in R:

```
system("python ./myScript.py 4 3")
```

and get

```
7
```

I want to store this result into a R object.

I tried

```
xx <- readline(system("python3 ../my_pythonScript.py 3 4"))
```

but do not get the 7 stored in `xx`

Comment: You don't need readline. Read help("system"), in particular the "Value" section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will cover three options:

1. [`system()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system.html): a base R function to invoke shell commands
2. [`system2()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system2.html): an alternative and slightly preferable base R function for the same purpose
3. [`processx`](https://processx.r-lib.org/reference/run.html): An extended version of `system()` and `system2()`, that gives you greater control, and more visibility into the running process.

#### Using `system()`

As Roland stated in the comments, you do not need `readline()`. However, with `system()`, to assign the output to `x` you need to set `intern = TRUE`. From the [docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system.html):

> `intern`: a logical (not NA) which indicates whether to capture the output of the command as an R character vector.

The default is `FALSE`, meaning the output is printed to the console rather than assigned.

```r
x  <- system(command = "python3 ./myScript.py 4 3", intern = TRUE)
x
# [1] "7"
```

#### Using `system2()`

Alternatively, you can use another base function `system2()`. Confusingly, the the first parameter is also `command`, but the syntax is slightly different. The second parameter is the arguments sent to the command. `system2()` does not have an `intern` parameter, but instead we tell it where to send `stdout`. As the [docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/system2.html) state:

> `stdout, stderr`: where output to `stdout` or `stderr` should be sent. Possible values are `""`, to the R console (the default), `NULL` or `FALSE` (discard output), `TRUE` (capture the output in a character vector) or a character string naming a file.

```r
y <- system2(
    command = "python3",
    args = "./myScript.py 4 3",
    stdout = TRUE
)
y
# [1] "7"
```

In both cases the result is a character vector. (Note also if you're copy/pasting I'm using `python3` rather than `python` here.)

#### Capturing errors (`stderr`)

In both cases, if you changed the command to generate an error, e.g. `./myScript.py a b`, the error would be printed to the console and `x` and `y` would be `character(0)`.

Using `system()`, we can redirect `stdout` to `stderr` in the normal `bash` way:

```r
x_err <- system(command = "python3 ./myScript.py a b 2>&1", intern = TRUE)
x_err
# [1] "Traceback (most recent call last):"                      "  File \"./myScript.py\", line 2, in <module>"          
# [3] "    print(int(sys.argv[2])+int(sys.argv[1]))"            "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'b'"
```

However, this only works on Unix-like OSes. If you try this on Windows, while the assignment still works if there's no error (in this case - definitely not always), if there is an error you get `character(0)`.

Conversely, we can explicitly redirect `stderr` using `system2()`:

```r
y_err <- system2(
    command = "python3",
    args = "./myScript.py a b",
    stdout = TRUE,
    stderr = TRUE
)
```

This returns the same output as `x_err` on Unix-like OSes and Windows, which I think is a good reason to prefer `system2()` to `system()`.

#### Arguments which require quotes

As highlighted in the comment by Konrad Rudolph, if we rename `myScript.py` to `name with spaces.py`, we'll see that it no longer works using `system()` or `system2()`:

##### `system()`

We do not get the desired output on Ubuntu or Windows (though in the former we can redirect the error):

```r
x <- system("python3 name with spaces.py 3 4 2>&1", intern = TRUE)
# bash (Ubuntu):
x # [1] "python3: can't open file 'bad': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"
# Windows:
x # character(0)
```

##### `system2()`

Again this does not work though in both cases with `system2()` we are able to capture the error:

```r
x <- system2("python", "./name with spaces.py 3 4", stdout = TRUE, stderr = TRUE)
# bash (Ubuntu):
x # [1] "python3: can't open file 'bad': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"
# Windows:
x # "c:\\python38\\python.exe: can't open file './bad': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"
```

#### `processx`

As highlighted by Konrad Rudolph, `processx` **does** quote arguments. [`processx::run()`](https://processx.r-lib.org/reference/run.html) returns a list with components:

> `status` The exit status of the process. If this is NA, then the process was killed and had no exit status.
> `stdout` The standard output of the command, in a character scalar.
> `stderr` The standard error of the command, in a character scalar.
> `timeout` Whether the process was killed because of a timeout.

This means it can handle filenames with spaces (and other special characters):

```r
x <- processx::run("python3", c("./name with spaces.py", "3", "4"))
# bash (Ubuntu):
x$stdout # "7\n"
# Windows:
x$stdout # "7\r\n"
```

And similarly if there are errors it can capture them:

```r
x <- processx::run("python3", c("./name with spaces.py", "a", "b"), error_on_status = FALSE)
# bash (Ubuntu):
x$stderr # "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"./name with spaces.py\", line 2, in <module>\n    print(int(sys.argv[2])+int(sys.argv[1]))\nValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'b'\n"
# Windows:
x$stderr # "Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"name with spaces.py\", line 2, in <module>\r\n    print(int(sys.argv[2])+int(sys.argv[1]))\r\nValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'b'\r\n"
```

Note that here I set `error_on_status = FALSE`. If set to `TRUE` it will throw an error in R, rather than returning the list with the `stderr` component.

`processx` also has other features such as timeouts, using non-blocking connections and checking if a background process is running. These are set out in this [blog post](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2018/09/processx-3.2.0/) and the [Github repo](https://github.com/r-lib/processx)

Comment: `system2()` is better than `system()` but beware that it’s still highly problematic because it does not quote the command line arguments (no idea why); and in fact for this reason your call happens to work but actually *should* use a vector (`args = c("myscript.py", "a", "b")`). In fact, you can see from its source code that it’s merely a wrapper for `system()`, rather than dispatching directly to the OS API. Therefore, unless limiting dependencies is a strong concern, I recommend using the ‘processx’ package, which is a vastly superior implementation.

Comment: @KonradRudolph thanks - I was just comparing the `system()` and `system2()` docs and trying to work out other significant similarities and differences. I will take a look at `processx` and try to update the answer.

Comment: Thank you and to @KonradRudolph for the detailed, well-researched answer: I really learnt a lot of new things here. And I have been using R since 1997 when we had to manually compile it!

Comment: Thanks to @SamR and Konrad Rudolph. Said separately to allow for mentions for each.

Comment: @user3236841 thanks! I learn a lot writing these answers as people like Konrad Rudolph can come and tell me what I've missed out! Incidentally I got notifications on both comments - I seem to get notifications for any comments on my answers.

Comment: I think you get points perhaps if you are mentioned with the @, though no idea why they can not be in one comment. Thank you both again!