# Using system() to run a bash script with input via read -r

Tags: r, rstudio

I have the following bash script (`test.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash

printf '\e[36m%s\e[0m' "This is a test"; echo ""

function yes_or_no {
    while true; do
        read -p "$* [y/n]: " yn
        case $yn in
            [Yy]*) return 0  ;;  
            [Nn]*) echo "Aborted" ; exit  1 ;;
        esac
    done
}

yes_or_no "Do you wish to continue? Y/n"
```

And I want to run it from within R using the `system()` command, i.e.

```
system("./test.sh")
```

When I do this, I get the following output in the console:

```
> system("./test.sh")
This is a test
```

at which point it hangs indefinitely unless I stop R. It seems like there is an issue with interactivity using the `read` command in bash. When I run from the Terminal I get

```
$ ./test.sh 
This is a test
Do you wish to continue? Y/n [y/n]: n
Aborted
```

Any ideas how to allow user input when calling bash scripts from R?

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib64/libopenblasp-r0.3.3.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] compiler  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
[7] methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] reticulate_1.31   stringi_1.7.12    data.table_1.14.7

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.10         pillar_1.8.1        R.methodsS3_1.8.2  
 [4] R.utils_2.12.2      tools_4.1.2         qs_0.25.5          
 [7] odbc_1.3.3          bit_4.0.5           jsonlite_1.8.4     
[10] lattice_0.20-45     timechange_0.2.0    lubridate_1.9.1    
[13] lifecycle_1.0.3     tibble_3.1.8        png_0.1-8          
[16] pkgconfig_2.0.3     rlang_1.1.0         Matrix_1.5-3       
[19] cli_3.6.0           DBI_1.1.3           rstudioapi_0.14    
[22] filelock_1.0.2      yaml_2.3.7          withr_2.5.0        
[25] dplyr_1.1.0         hms_1.1.2           generics_0.1.3     
[28] edris_1.3.0         vctrs_0.5.2         rappdirs_0.3.3     
[31] grid_4.1.2          rprojroot_2.0.3     bit64_4.0.5        
[34] tidyselect_1.2.0    glue_1.6.2          here_1.0.1         
[37] RApiSerialize_0.1.2 R6_2.5.1            fansi_1.0.4        
[40] purrr_1.0.1         blob_1.2.3          magrittr_2.0.3     
[43] ellipsis_0.3.2      assertthat_0.2.1    keyring_1.3.1      
[46] utf8_1.2.3          stringfish_0.15.7   RcppParallel_5.1.7 
[49] sodium_1.2.1        crayon_1.5.2        R.oo_1.25.0
```

Comment: @oguzismail still hangs

Comment: I'm not familiar with "*)" but added this line on a new line at the end and no difference

Comment: I can't replicate this issue. The shell script works as intended when called from the terminal with `./test.sh` and in R `system("./test.sh")` behaves identically - asking for input and responding as expected. This is with R 4.2.2 on Ubuntu 20.04. Can you post your `sessionInfo()`? Also worth saying which IDE you're using and whether this problem also happens in `R` from the terminal. Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77255792/store-result-of-system-call-in-r-object/77256951) question - see if you have any success with `system2("./test.sh")` or `processx::run("./test.sh")`.

Comment: Works fine for me with R 4.3.3 on Ubuntu 22.04.3. However, within RStudio 2023.12.1 Build 402, it FAILS! Are you using R directly or within RStudio?

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone - with RStudio - session info added to original comments

Comment: No luck with system2 or processx::run

Comment: Appears to be another RStudio bug, tag added.